# Поправить перевод. Сейчас: "Вопрос был закрыто"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Правильно: вопрос был закрыт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это уведомление появляется, когда пишешь ответ и вопрос был закрыт во время набора ответа.

Comment: [Эволюция](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymwUI.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

В transifex упомянутая строка выглядит так:

> [Вопрос был $message$ — новые ответы приниматься не будут.](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261889?key=86d533b46453d2b9bdfc7471b57209a0)

Оригинал:

> This question has been $message$ - no more answers will be accepted.

Т.о. `закрыто` пролезает из другой строки, судя по всему это [`closed`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263648?key=349e686330723975502e9ef4f939a5ac).

В таких случаях менять `закрыто` на `закрыт` может быть чревато (деструктивными) изменениями в других местах. Лучшим решением было бы формирование новых самодостаточных строк, но это может произойти нескоро (читай, "никогда"). Поэтому предлагаю попробовать заменить, и посмотреть поедет ли где-то остальной перевод из-за такой замены. Если не получится найти подходящий для всех случаев вариант - придётся настаивать на добавлении новых полновесных строк. А возможно, что вариант с `закрыт` будет в других контекстах даже лучшим выбором. Короче говоря, пока не изменишь - не поймёшь :)

Вспомнил, где я как раз хотел заменить `закрыто` на `закрыт`. Это временная шкала, например для [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/582393/timeline):

> [image: шкала]

Но не решился именно по причине того, что строка могла быть использована в разных контекстах.

---

Составные строки были исключены из движка, добавлены новые самодостаточные и для них сделан перевод:

- id:9864

  > This question has been locked - no more answers will be accepted.

  > Вопрос был заблокирован — новые ответы приниматься не будут.
- id:9865

  > This question has been deleted - no more answers will be accepted.

  > Вопрос был удалён — новые ответы приниматься не будут.
- id:9866

  > This question has been closed - no more answers will be accepted.

  > Вопрос был закрыт — новые ответы приниматься не будут.

Дополнительно перевод ранее упомянутого `closed` был изменён на `закрыт` в нескольких контекстах.